# Android/SQLite. Can't add new value to column bacause logcat says the column not unique, but I defined it as unique?

Tags: android, database, unique

Maybe here are some problem in creating the table, but I can't figure out.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column number is not unique (code 19)

String CREATE_SMSData_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE version3 ("
            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "number TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE )";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SMSData_TABLE);
```

My insert operation:

```
public void addData(SMSData data) {

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_NUMBER, data.getNumber());   

db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values); 
db.close();
```

}

Comment: Yes, the value you were adding was not unique in that column.

Comment: can u show your insert operation

Comment: I inserted my insert operation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a unique value in the "number" column.  It is the same for each insert.  You have marked the column as UNIQUE, and are attempting to insert the same value multiple times.

Either guarantee a unique value for the "number" column, in the ContentValues, for each insert, or remove the UNIQUE constraint from the table.

**Edited to add additional case:**

... or, I suppose, if the value really is supposed to be unique, catch the Exception and take appropriate action.